# Show convergence using CLT

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $1/2$. Let  $S=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. Using the Central Limit Theorem, show that 
$$
\frac{|2S-n|}{\sqrt n}
$$
is convergent to a standard normal random variable.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want the absolute values there.

Comment: I am interesting in the result with absolute values. Is it possible to show?

Comment: With absolute values you get convergence to a [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of $S$ is $\frac{n}{2}$ and its variance is $\frac{n}{4}$ so $$\frac{S - \frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}}} = \frac{2S - n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges to a standard normal distribution by the Central Limit Theorem.

The absolute value of a normal distribution with mean $0$ is a  [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) so $$\frac{|2S - n|}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges to a half-normal distribution with mean $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.